# alert dialog not showing up when leaving app while toast does android

Tags: android, bluetooth, android-alertdialog

I am using code from Bluetooth Chat sample application. I want while the user leaves the app, he should be able to receive data. So If I do this:

```
 case MESSAGE_READ:
                byte[] readBuf = (byte[]) msg.obj;
                // construct a string from the valid bytes in the buffer
                String readMessage = new String(readBuf, 0, msg.arg1);
                mConversationArrayAdapter.add(mConnectedDeviceName+":  " + readMessage);
                /***************************ADDED***************************/
                System.out.println("Number is"+(int)(readMessage.charAt(0)));

                /***************************ADDED***************************/
                break;
```

I do see in the DDMS the println statement.

If I do this:

```
 case MESSAGE_READ:
                byte[] readBuf = (byte[]) msg.obj;
                // construct a string from the valid bytes in the buffer
                String readMessage = new String(readBuf, 0, msg.arg1);
                mConversationArrayAdapter.add(mConnectedDeviceName+":  " + readMessage);
                /***************************ADDED***************************/
                System.out.println("Number is"+(int)(readMessage.charAt(0)));
               Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "received!! "
                        + mConnectedDeviceName, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

                /***************************ADDED***************************/
                break;
```

I do see the toast message even if I leave the application and I am in other apps.

Finally what I really want is no matter if my app is not running when I receive a specific data, open up a alert dialog, and if I press yes for example make something (i want to make an http request on yes, and on no be transfeered to my app.)

This is my code:

```
 case MESSAGE_READ:
                byte[] readBuf = (byte[]) msg.obj;
                // construct a string from the valid bytes in the buffer
                String readMessage = new String(readBuf, 0, msg.arg1);
                mConversationArrayAdapter.add(mConnectedDeviceName+":  " + readMessage);
                /***************************ADDED***************************/

                new AlertDialog.Builder(getApplicationContext())
                .setTitle("Title")
                .setMessage("Message")
                .setPositiveButton("Yes",
                 new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                     public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                          //make http request
                }
             })
                .setNegativeButton("No",
                          new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                             // @Override
                              public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                                   //open my app
                               }

                          }).show();


                /***************************ADDED***************************/
                break;
```

And in that case when I leave my app, and receive data I get a force close. I suppose the argment getApplicationContext is wrong but I do not know what to use.

Sollution: I used a Notification instead.

Comment: I have had this similar problem where I wanted an AlertDialog to appear at the end of the Activity. It does, but if I leave early or exit. I get a force close because the Activity is closed, but the AlertDialog wants to pop up. The best way is to probably have a Toast message or Notification.

Comment: I used a Notification instead.